# How to handle cors headers between a django backend and react js frontend

Tags: django, fetch-api, django-cors-headers

I am running my react js on frontend.domain.com and backend on backend.domain.com. I am trying to fetch the data from backend django api using the backend.domain.com url. But I am getting this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://backend.domain.com/login/' from origin 'https://frontend.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What settings should set in my django backend api like in settings.py or any other. Or in the frontend react js ?

What changes should I do to access the resources of the django using frontend react js!

How to handle that error and what changes should i make in backend to make access the frontend react js

Answer (score 0):

#### Follow those steps...

install (**`pip install django-cors-headers`**)

#### settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders', # <-------- this
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # <-------- this
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'sales_company_app.get_user_instance.RequestMiddleware',
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # <-------- this
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",    # React (FrontEnd Url) # <-------- this
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = '*' # <-------- this
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://192.168.1.155:8000/"] # (Api Base Url) <-------- this (allow csrf_token) for doing whitelist
```

Comment: That's great for local development, but it's not recommended for a production environment