# Django forbidden (csrf cookie not set.): /products/ Error

Tags: python, django

I've gone through a lot of other threads and discussion forums, but none solved exactly.
This solution refers to few settings in the settings.py I've applied them, [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

I'm posting this question because I've tried other solutions but none exactly fixed it.

This is also a just the beginning of a server, I made the project, started an app, & created a view for POST request. Let me know if any other code is required...

My views.py nothing, just a basic return. When I add `@csrf_exempt` it works but I can't really do that.

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json


# Create your views here.
def Product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)  # Parse JSON data from the request body
            if "data" in data:
                response_data = str(data["data"])  # Get the value of 'data' key
                return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
            else:
                return HttpResponse(
                    "Invalid JSON data. 'data' key is missing.", status=400
                )
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid JSON data.", status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("This API only accepts POST requests.")
```

`Settings.py`

```py
"""
Django settings for app_server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

import environ
from pathlib import Path

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = None

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    # Add other trusted origins here if needed
]

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    # Add other cookie domain here if needed
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    # Add other CSRF trusted origins here if needed
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "*"
    # "localhost",
    # Add other allowed hosts here if needed
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "products",
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly",
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "app_server.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "app_server.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

I'm making a request from React frontend as:

```js
  function getCSRFToken() {
    const csrfCookie = document.cookie.match(/(^|;)csrftoken=([^;]+)/);
    return csrfCookie ? csrfCookie[2] : "";
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const csrfToken = getCSRFToken();

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: 1,
        info: "No",
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
      },
    }).then((response) => console.log(response));
  };
```

I've tried printing the csrfToken and it's valid. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass **API Base url** not **frontend url** in  **`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`**

write

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://192.168.1.155:8000/"] <- api base url (backend-url)
```

instead of

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",<- write here api base url (backend-url not frontend url)
    # Add other CSRF trusted origins here if needed
]
```

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication" # need for set cookies 
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Making it like `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1:8000",]` will give `Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://localhost:3000 does not match any trusted origins.): /products/` so I have to add that `"http://localhost:3000"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528747/19205926

Comment: answer is updated plzz check it